# Global changes to maven surefire plugin in .m2/settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I would like to change the default setting for `maven-surefire-plugin`, and instead of using `<reportFormat>brief</reportFormat>`, I would like to use `<reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>`.

Usually, I would achieve this by modifying an individual `pom` for a project, such as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
        <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, is it possible to somehow modify `~/.m2/settings.xml` file and set `<reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>` as a default behaviour for all maven projects I want to compile.
I do an analysis of many maven projects, so I would prefer to change the behaviour on global level rather than modifying `pom` files for each individual project.

Comment: You should use a corporate pom where you define such default things you like to have for the company but the settings.xml is not the right location for it nor is it possible to do so...but this requires you have already used a coporate pom file...

Answer (score 1):

The `settings.xml` configuration file doesn't go down at this level of detail. The plugin configuration can be specified only in the pom.xml
The best way to check it is studying the settings.xml schema :

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd

You could see that the single elements referencing the "plugin" word have no relation with the plugin configuration in the build.

For your requirement, the single solution that has also its drawbacks if bad used is using a parent pom that defines the plugin configuration and that all Maven modules should have as parent to inherit from the plugin configuration and potentially from other things.

If your applicative projets use a multi module/parent pom structure, I think that a nicer solution would be to declare this configuration in the parent pom of each multi module/parent pom.
In this way you declare it multiple times but a single time by set of related projects.

Comment: that's really unfortunate, but I guess very specific as well. your solution seem to be similar to what I was thinking before I thought that some global settings could be changed. anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: you are welcome. I understand well your point. Sometimes, we have to do some trade-offs :)